# graphql-tools: lazy fetching?

Tags: javascript, graphql-js, apollo-server

I'm trying to simplify a graphql server using Apollo's graphql-tools.  I want to do lazy-fetching, but not able to return a promise the way I could when using javascript classes as the resolvers.

Here's what I got:

Schema

```
type Customer {
    details: Contact!
    addresses: [Address]!
}
    extend type Query {
        customers(first: Int = 0, next: Int = 50): [Customer]
        customer(id: Int!): Customer
    }
```

Resolver

```
const domain1Resolvers = {
    Query: {
        customers: (_, {
            first,
            next
        }) => customers(first, next)
    }
};
```

resolving method:

```
const customers = (first, next) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        var q =
            `
                SELECT *, company as organization FROM customer
                ORDER BY id DESC
                LIMIT ?, ?`;
        sql.query(q, [first, next], function(err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                throw Error(err);
            }
            resolve(rows.map(r => {
                return {
                    details: r,
                    addresses: () => getAddresses(r.id),
                }
            }));
        });
    })
};
```

The method getAddresses is invoked only if addresses is requested.  In the class-based approach, I am able to have getAddresses return a Promise, but it will complain about not returning an Iterable if I try that using this mechanism. There must be some way of fetching addresses only when requested, but drawing a blank and so far not found an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve a field on Customer only when it is requested, you would want to utilize the resolver for that particular field rather than the resolver for the `customers` query. Your resolvers would look something like this:

```
const domain1Resolvers = {
  Query: {
    customers: (_, {
      first,
      next
    }) => customers(first, next)
  },
  Customer: {
    addresses: ({ details: { id } }) => getAddresses(id)
  },
};
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.  I hadn't come across anything like that.